# NodeJS sometimes exist after runtime error but sometimes not

Tags: loopbackjs

I'm using loopback 3 which based on expressJS. I noticed that sometimes the nodeJS app exit when runtime error occurs but sometimes just showing the error but not exit and the app continue functioning.

Can someone explain in what types of runtime errors the entire app terminates and what type not?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to check your code carefully, it looks like you missed "await" for a promise somewhere. Generally, all errors should be caught by the error handler (if we are token about requests processing)